# Sistema de marcação e anotação para usuário

Tags: laravel, annotation

Olá, sou novo em programação e estou tentando desenvolver uma plataforma educacional para minha empresa.

Até o momento, tenho os capítulos salvos no meu banco de dados como richtext e os alunos poderão acessar os mesmo através de url's do tipo:
`/student/content/{block}/{discipline}/{chapter}`.

- `block`: blocos que dividem o curso em pedaços menores.

Gostaria de saber se é possível incluir um sistema que permita aos alunos selecionar uma parte do texto da pagina gerada e adicionar um comentário a esse texto, salvar no banco de dados, e apresentar  esse comentário quando o aluno voltar a essa página em outro momento.

Seria algo similar a essa extensão do chrome, mas seria bem simples, apenas o comentário em texto simples, um botão para criar/editar e um para excluir a anotação.

Extensão: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/notesalong-advanced-web-p/egpbgcdjicaeknfhonheocaepjcabbjg

Estou usando laraval no back, tenho mais habilidade com php, mas me viro com vue.js

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda de todos!

Comment: Sim é possível, existem várias estratégias que poderia adotar. O ideal seria reformular sua pergunta postando o que já tentou em relação à código ou estrutura desta funcionalidade

Comment: Ai que está o problema, não faço ideia de como fazer isso. Poderia me dar algumas ideias bases para que eu possa pesquisar e depois reformular?

Comment: Precisaria de mais detalhes da regra de negócio e possibilidades de solução aceitas, além da modelagem do banco, e ao menos uma visão geral do que está desenvolvido neste módulo até o momento

Comment: É um site de venda de curso preparatório, para institutos federais e vestibulares. Ao adquirir o curso, por meio de chave de parceiros ou compra online o aluno ganha acesso a página dos conteúdos. Essas páginas são salvas em uma tabela como richtext e são carregadas nas páginas de acordo com os capítulos escolhidos pelos alunos. O acesso a esse conteúdo pode ser feito por alunos ou professores, ambos devem ter acesso a esse recurso. Penso em salvar cada comentário em uma tabela no banco junto do id do usuário e url onde a marcação foi feita.

Comment: Porém, não sei como permitir que o usuário faça a marcação, como salvar a parte do texto selecionada e principalmente, como renderizar para o usuário a marcação quando o mesmo acessar a pagina novamente.